# Почему при регистрации возвращается только username и email?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, сериализация

Всем привет, столкнулся с такой проблемой что мой сериализатор **RegisterSerializer** после метода **create()** возвращает только *username* и *email*.

Вот мой сериализатор:

```
class RegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField(
        required=True,
        validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())]
    )
    password = serializers.CharField(
        write_only=True, required=True, validators=[validate_password])
    password2 = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=True)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'password', 'password2',
            'email',)
        
    def validate(self, attrs):
        if attrs['password'] != attrs['password2']:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                {"password": "Password fields didn't match."})
        return attrs
    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create(
            username=validated_data['username'],
            email=validated_data['email'],
            is_active=False
        )
        
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()
        code = random.randint(11111111, 99999999)
        code_r = f'confirm_email/?activation_id={code}&user_id={user.id}'
        url = f'http://26.21.163.167:3000/{code_r}'
        userprof = userProfile.objects.create(
            user=user,
        )
        email_receiver = User.objects.get(id = user.id).email
        subject = 'С успешной регистрацией!'
        body = f"Четотам четотма четотам вот ваша ссылка {url} переходи и регайся"
        EmailSend(email_sender=EMAIL_SENDER, passw=EMAIL_PASS, email_receiver=email_receiver, body=body, subject=subject) 
        
        

        userprof.save()
        return {'username': user.username, 'email': user.email, 'user_id':user.pk, 'url': code_r}
```

и при выполнении регистрации он мне должен вернуть то что в return, но он возвращает вот это:

```
{
    "username": "kuanan",
    "email": "kuanan@mail.ru"
}
```

А должно быть что-то по типу такого:

```
{
    "username": "kuanan",
    "email": "kuanan@mail.ru",
    "url": "какой то url",
    "user_id": 1,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте такой вариант:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    user = User.objects.create(
        username=validated_data['username'],
        email=validated_data['email'],
        is_active=False
    )
    
    user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
    user.save()
    code = random.randint(11111111, 99999999)
    code_r = f'confirm_email/?activation_id={code}&user_id={user.id}'
    url = f'http://26.21.163.167:3000/{code_r}'
    userprof = userProfile.objects.create(
        user=user,
    )
    email_receiver = User.objects.get(id=user.id).email
    subject = 'С успешной регистрацией!'
    body = f"Четотам четотма четотам вот ваша ссылка {url} переходи и регайся"
    EmailSend(email_sender=EMAIL_SENDER, passw=EMAIL_PASS, email_receiver=email_receiver, body=body, subject=subject) 

    userprof.save()
    
    validated_data['user_id'] = user.pk
    validated_data['url'] = code_r
    
    return validated_data
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас в сериализаторе выводятся и обрабатываются только поля  `fields = ('username', 'password', 'password2', 'email',)`. 2 из них - только для записи. Добавьте нужные поля только для вывода. Остальное на ваше усмотрение